# ASP.NET MVC 4 to Generate URL Formate as Controller/Action/ID

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the default route defined as

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

I want to generate a url like this in html -

```
<form action="/app/Request/c35d4520-ba0b-452f-837b-a00046f40647 method="post">
```

But if I code Razor page like -

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Default", "Request", FormMethod.Post, new { id = ViewBag.AppId }))
```

The rendered html is -

```
<form action="/app/Request" id="c35d4520-ba0b-452f-837b-a00046f40647" method="post">
```

How can I force the razor generate the url as controller/action/ID format?

Thanks

Comment: @{string a = ViewBag.a;}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Default/" + a, "Request", FormMethod.Post, new {  })) {  }


Lazy people like me would do it like this. But you should write a custom helper if this is required everywhere in the application.

Comment: The first 2 arguments to `BeginForm()` are [`string actionName` and `string controllerName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492714.aspx) and relate to the `{action}` and `{controller}` in the `url`. Does your application have an `appController` with a `Request` method to match `/app/Request/`? If so, `Html.BeginForm("Request", "app", ...)`.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski, thanks. I don't have a appController with a method named Request to match /app/Request/.

Comment: @Lakshay, thanks.  If I do that way, I will get an error as - Compiler Error Message: CS1973: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<RequestDto>>' has no applicable method named 'BeginForm' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.
I don't know why the error mentioned the class RequestDto.  I don't call the class in that line.

Comment: @Don i tried it myself before commenting, and its working fine..Sorry dont know why this is happening in your case

Comment: @Lakshay, thanks for your help any way.  The application I inherent is quite complicated and is confusing me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved by a function -

```
protected ActionResult RedirectToAppAction(string controllerName)
{
    return this.Redirect(string.Format("/App/{0}/{1}", controllerName, this.Id));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`Html.BeginRouteForm`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginrouteform%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

```
@using (Html.BeginRouteForm("Default", new { controller = "foo", action = "bar" }, FormMethod.Post, new { id="foo", enctype="multipart/form-data", accept_charset="utf-8" }))
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in the way you arrange the parameters in the `Html.BeginForm` call. According to the parameters you feed in, you are currently calling

```
Html.BeginForm(actionName, controllerName, formMethod, htmlAttributes)
```

Therefore, `new { id = ViewBag.AppId }` is treated as htmlAttributes. And that is why the `id` is renedered as an attribute in the form tag.

Instead, you should swap the positions of method and the id as below

```
Html.BeginForm("Default", "Request", new { id = ViewBag.AppId }, FormMethod.Post))
```

Let me know if it works for you :)